# Image Processing Toolkits - GD2 vs ImageMagick - Codecs

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd

Are compression algorithms all the same since they're being used to generate a common format?

For example, let's say you set GD2 to output JPEG at 60% quality.  Would the output be the same as ImageMagick at 60% quality?

Over the years I've built up an anecdotal based belief that ImageMagick's image algorithm is better and therefore the images generated are a higher quality - but is that belief true?

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely unlikely they would be the same. The JPEG standard permits codecs to make their own decisions, within certain constraints, as to whether they use integer or float maths to get more speed or accuracy, how much rounding and discarding they do, which quantisation tables they use and to what extent they sub-sample the colours. Interesting discussion [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) under *"Codec Example"* heading.

I have made no assessment of the relative quality/accuracy of any particular codecs.